# Asterisk и AMI Originate (инициация вызова по AMI)

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Добрый вечер!
Такая проблема: в Asterisk при инициации вызова через интерфейс AMI, если екстеншен занят(разговаривает), ВЫЗОВ НЕ ОТБИВАЕТСЯ. Если же на телефончике включен режим DND, или отбить вручную, то он отбивается, как и надо:

```
-- Called 198
-- SIP/198-00000d90 is busy
```

Команды AMI:

```
Action:Originate
ActionID:1234
Channel:SIP/198
Context:from-internal
Priority:1
Exten:0991112233
Async:false
CallerId:obzvon
Timeout:30000
```

Asterisk 12.5.0, FreePBX 12.0.7.
Диалплан стандартный, не менялся.

CallWaiting Disable

ставил в AMI Context: default - не помогло

Answer (score 2):

Context:Local/198@from-internal решило проблему.